# Count characters in textfield on keydown event

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I want to live update the amount of characters entered in a textfield as the user puts them in. I am not getting too far. This is what I have so far. It changes to zero. I'm rather new to javascript to a beginner explanation would be great.

```js
function doThis() {
  x = document.getElementById("area").textContent;
  y = x.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area" onkeydown="doThis()"></textarea>
<p id="demo">Count goes here</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the content of the `textarea` use `.value` and change the event to `onkeyup`.

```js
function doThis() {
  x = document.getElementById("area").value;
  y = x.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area" onkeyup="doThis()"></textarea>
<p id="demo">Count goes here</p>
```

Comment: @NabilKadimi - `onkeydown` will trigger when you press the key and `onkeyup` will trigger when you release the key. If you use the first event, you won't get all characters of the `textarea`. You will get one less, so if there are `5` characters, it will show `4`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `textcontent`  use `value` and if you want to use keydown, add +1

```js
function doThis() {
  x = document.getElementById("area").value;
  y = x.length + 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area" onkeydown="doThis()"></textarea>
<p id="demo">Count goes here</p>
```

note: if you copy and paste it will give you wrong result, so better to use `onkeyup`

Comment: The `+1` will provide a wrong count when using copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer with [**`.querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) and less code:

```js
document.querySelector('#area').onkeyup = function() {
  document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = this.value.length;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
<p id="demo">Count goes here</p>
```